# Retrieve Record from Database based on Local Time

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Let's suppose I live in a timezone where Today Date is: 12/3/2014
Before saving record I save the date in UTC, so it would be 12/2/2014

```
user.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Now I have a Search page on which I would like to retrieve record based on the filter "Today". Also I would like to truncate time so I am using DbFunction of EF.

```
 DateTime dateDifference = DateTime.Now.Date;
 var result= queryableData
       .Where(s => dateDifference ==
         DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(s.Created.Year, s.Created.Month,
             s.Created.Day, 0, 0, 0)).AsQueryable();
```

The above query does not return any record because the stored date is in UTC which 12/2/2014, however I am living in a timezone where date is 12/3/2014. So it make sense, how can I modify the above query to meet my requirement. Any suggestion

Comment: What is the type in the database? Date or DateTime?

Comment: Data Type is DateTime and the record value save as 12/2/2014 1:41 PM in UTC.

Comment: If you define "local today" as the date range of midnight + 24 hours , then you can just translate "local today" into "UTC today" and use that as your search criteria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that we know that the value is stored as a `DateTime` (in UTC), you just need to find the UTC time of midnight at the start of today, and the UTC time of midnight at the end of today.

If you're happy to use the system time zone, you could use:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime startUtc = today.ToUniversalTime();
DateTime endUtc = today.AddDays(1).ToUniversalTime();

var result = queryableDate.Where(s => startUtc <= s.Created &&
                                      s.Created < endUtc);
```

I don't think you *should* need `DbFunctions` for that query. Basically, you don't need a *difference* at all - you just need to work out what your filter of "today" means in terms of an interval in time, expressed as UTC.

Comment: It works great. Thanks a lot. But I am still confuse how it is working. Can you please elaborate Sir

Comment: @AmmarKhan: It's hard to elaborate when I don't know what you understand. For example, if you're in the west coast of America, then "today" (December 2nd) runs from 2014-12-02T08:00:00Z to 2014-12-03T08:00:00Z, so that's what you'd want the filter in the query to do.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your local date to universal time.

> DateTime universalDate = dateDifference.ToUniversalTime();